# Последовательный ответ от бота

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Как можно сделать цепочку ответов для бота. К примеру

- Бот: Укажите свое имя
- Я: Имя
- Бот: Хорошо, теперь фамилию
- Я: Фамилия
- Бот: И теперь отчество
- Я: Отчество

```cs
if (e.Message.Text == ("Заполнить анкету"))
{
    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Укажите свое имя");
}
```

А вот что дальше понятия не имею)

Comment: Если сразу к делу, то поизучайте такой алгоритм "конечный автомат".

Comment: Проще говоря - вам нужно запоминать состояние сессии(отдельно взятого чата пользователя или обращения от конкретного пользователя если чат общий).

Comment: Еще то, что вы описали, похоже на паттерн State (но это не отменяет комментария от Геннадия)